# Uwp Bind Co-ordinate values using mvvm

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

```
 <Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Path Stroke="Black"  StrokeThickness="2">
            <Path.Data>                    
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure  x:Name="UpperCircle" StartPoint="0,150">
                        <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True"
                            Size="50, 50"
                            Point="300, 150"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    </PathFigure>
                    <PathFigure  x:Name="LeftLine"
                                StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint.X,ElementName=UpperCircle},150"                                    
                                >
                        <LineSegment Point="50,280" />
                    </PathFigure> 
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Hi I want to bind LeftLine X VALUE from Start point of Upper Circle.I have tried using binding but it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Binding}` is a markup extension, a special syntax in XAML. And `StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint.X, ElementName=UpperCircle},150"` is not XAML-compliant.

Try this:

```xml
<PathFigure  x:Name="LeftLine"
        StartPoint="{Binding ElementName=UpperCircle,Path=StartPoint}" 
        >
    <LineSegment Point="50,280" />
</PathFigure>
```

If you want to know about XAML syntax and `Binding`, the following documents can help you:

1. [XAML overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-overview#markup-extensions)
2. [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart)

Best regards.

Comment: Hi Richard thanks for the suggestion,But my intention is to bind only one co-ordinate (X)value of start point from other and Y Coordinate from other section,So I have tried like StartPoint="X,Y"  to bind like StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint.X,ElementName=UpperCircle},{Binding StartPoint.Y,ElementName=BottomCircle}" .This was causing error unexpected ,

Comment: Hi, You can understand that `{Binding}` is an expression. There can be only one expression in a property. In other words, there can only be a pair of curly brackets (`{ }`) in a pair of quotes (`" "`). `StartPoint` is a `Point` object. Although the "0,150" you entered is a string, it will be converted to a `Point` object and assigned to `StartPoint` at compile time. The binding requires that the bound object and the target are of the same type, which means that you must bind a `Point` object, and a single `X` or `Y` is only a `double` type, which cannot be matched.